# Entity Framework Core 5 - Single Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 5 and I'm having problems retrieving records with all of their associated related data.  As you can see below, I have three classes; Person, Client and ReferralPerson.  Both Client and ReferralPerson contain Person objects and Client also contains a ReferralPerson object.

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "N/A";

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "N/A";

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string PhoneNumberPrimary { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string PhoneNumberSecondary { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

}

public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CommunicationMethod { get; set; }
    public DateTime InitalContactDate { get; set; }       

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string ReasonForVisit { get; set; }
    public ReferralPerson ReferralPerson { get; set; }

}

public class ReferralPerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfReferrals { get; set; }

}
```

My OnModelCreating() method currently looks like the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //setup our relationships
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Person);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
        .HasOne(c => c.ReferralPerson);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ReferralPerson>().ToTable("ReferralContacts");

}
```

Finally, I have a method that's used for searching Client records as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetClientsByLastName(string lastName)
{
    var query = db.Clients
                  .Include(x => x.Person)
                  .Include(x => x.ReferralPerson)
                  .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || 
                    x.Person.LastName.Contains(lastName))
                  .ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Looking at the database tables that are created by the migration, I can see that the relationships appear to be correct between the Clients table, Person (People) table and ReferralContacts table.  I can also see that records are being added correctly to these tables when I save a new record.  The issue is with the retrieving.  Even though I am using ".Include(x => x.Person)" in the "GetClientsByLastName()" method, the person object does not get populated when retrieving a Client record.  I've spent quite a bit of time looking at other posts and solutions as well as the EF Core documentation, but I'm still missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 5-9-2022:

Here is the EF generated SQL query from the LINQ Query shown above

```
DECLARE @__lastName_0 nvarchar(50) = N'bur';
SELECT [c].[ID], 
[c].[CommunicationMethod], 
[c].[InitalContactDate], 
[c].[PersonID], 
[c].[ReasonForVisit],
[c].[ReferralPersonID],
[p].[ID],
[p].[Address],
[p].[EmailAddress],
[p].[FirstName],
[p].[LastName],
[p].[PhoneNumberPrimary],
[p].[PhoneNumberSecondary],
[r].[ID],
[r].[BusinessName],
[r].[NumberOfReferrals],
[r].[PersonID]
FROM [Clients] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [People] AS [p] ON [c].[PersonID] = [p].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [ReferralContacts] AS [r] ON [c].[ReferralPersonID] = [r].[ID]
WHERE (@__lastName_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__lastName_0, [p].[LastName]) > 0)
ORDER BY [p].[LastName]
```

When I execute that SQL Query in SSMS all of the related data is being retrieved as expected, so the issue does not appear to be in the query.  It is how that data is then being populated into the underlying objects that is the issue.

Comment: *being added correctly to these tables* - so there truly is a Person in the DB for any given Client X?

Comment: What is your DB? why you are using `.ToLower()?` and what is the meaning of "the person object does not get populated when retrieving a Client record." ? are you getting an exception?

Comment: @Mohi The database is MS SQL Server. The "ToLower()" should not be there, as it is not needed.  When I say the person object is not populated, no, there is no exception, just the properties of that object are null.

Comment: @CaiusJard  Yes!  Currently there is only one record in each table, as I am in the early testing stages.  But there is one person record for the one Client record right now.

Comment: @Pungo120 by the way, you don't need ToLower() for MS SQL Server because it is already case insensitive.

Comment: Show us the SQL that is generated by that query. If youre using EFC5+, comment out the ToList() and inspect the DebugView property of `query`. Also show us the tables contents

Comment: @CaiusJard  Edited my original post to include the query.  As you can see by the note I added below that query, when I execute that query in SSMS, all of the related data is retrieved as expected, so the issue is not with the SQL Query.  It has to do with how that data is then being extracted into the underlying objects that is the issue.  Specifically, the child object (Person & ReferralPerson) properties.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue with .net6/efc6

Comment: @Mohi cannot make assumptions about collation

Comment: Can you post a complete project to github, including an MDF that can be attached?

Comment: @CaiusJard You have a point there.

Comment: @CaiusJard Below is a link to the GitHub repository with a backup copy of the database in the root folder.  You'll just need to do a restore on the database.
https://github.com/dburke555/ClientDatabase

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question. The question and answer can't be understood without it.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you're setting up this empty data you're seeing, and EFC won't overwrite it if you do. Comment out/delete all your entity constructors that are doing things like this:

```
    public Client()
    {
        Person = new Person(0, "", "");
        ContactType = new ContactType();
        ReferralPerson = new ReferralPerson();
        NewsletterOption = new NewsletterOption();
    }
```

If the entities are made so as to look like those presented in the *question*, everything works

Comment: No problem! PS; I find it faster to do solo dev by setting the database and relationships up in the DB and then scaffold it into C#. The scaffolded code won't exhibit this problem

Comment: So basically database first vs code first!  Makes sense!

Comment: Yep. Also the EFCore Power Tools extension makes doing that re-scaffold about 3 mouse clicks, and offers a lot of options for customzing the process/remembers your choices between scaffs so it's relatively painless